# Frame and components in java

Tags: java

I know frame is act as container object that we can add components , there are many of components  in swing package ( like button , menu and table etc...)
I have tried to add table to frame but I could not , why ??
unless I have add scroll pane object to frame then add table to scroll pane so what is difference between frame and scroll pane ? why I cannot add table directly to frame and what are real benefits of scroll pane for table

in this code , the table is shown with very small size and in corner and when add table directly to frame I cannot see any thing

```
   Test t1=new Test(Test.Accounts());

    ScrollPane scroll=new ScrollPane();
    scroll.add(t1);
    add(scroll);
```

note Test class is act as table class because I have extend it with JTable class and this code inside JFrame constructor

Comment: ScrollPane is not a Swing component it is a AWT component. You should really avoid mixing the two component types. What you want to use is **JScrollPane**.

Comment: Instead of randomly putting things together you should go your way through the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ also please enhance your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell Java how large you want the Table to be. You can do so by either set the size manually with `t1.setBounds(x, y, width, height)`, or by using a layout. If you want to set the bounds manually you have to check that no layout is being used. You can do so by setting the layout to null: `frame.setLayout(null);`.

You can set the container's layout by `frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` where in this case I'm using a BorderLayout (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). Now you can add the table and tell Java to fill the whole frame by typing `frame.add(t1, BorderLayout.CENTER)`. `CENTER` can be replaced by `NORTH`, `EAST`, `SOUTH`, `WEST` depending on where you want the table to be.